# Is it nesessary to separate data structures and algorithms for 2D and 3D geometry and mechanical problems?

Tags: 3d, geometry, 2d

I have developed a library which can solve 3d geometry problems and specific 3d mechanical problems .

Now, I am invited to design a similar library to solve 2D problems.

Do I need to redefined similiar data structures and algorithms for 2D case again?

Could anyone give me some advices ?

If I should redefined these for 2D library, could you show me some cases that it is nessary to separate 2D and 3D library ?

---

For example, an algorithm to solve if one point is inside a polygon can be shared between 2D and 3D problem. In this case, using 3D data structures and alogrithms to sovle 2D problem is enough.

For geometry problem, I feel like that the difference is wether a point contain "z" value.

But I am afraid if there are case that 3D algorithm is not suitable for 2D problems?

Or some other reasons that separating data structures and algorithms is nesessary.

Comment: Question  seems too broad.

Comment: Thanks, MBo.  I am going to develop numerical software (like Finite Element Method software) which have to deal with geometry and mechanical problems at same time. Could you give me some hints to make question more clear?

Comment: Maybe it is helpful to know precisely *why* you have been invited to do that.

Answer (score 0):

SO format assumes more specific questions (although you have added some description).

I think that usage of 3d functions would cause resource wasting and sometimes overcomplication.

For instance, compare 3d vector product with 2d cross product.

Also some 2D problems have no direct 3D analogs (for instance `is left/right to...` notion)

Comment: I agree with you about "resource wasting and sometimes overcomplication". Then what about 2D and 3D library share same geometry data structure?

Comment: I think the most of structures should be separated (but I'm not ready to say what ones might be shared, and what should be separated - this is rather complex architectural question)

Answer (score 0):

Most of our code is 3D and we still use it also for 2D when relevant. Our software is for 3D modeling in GIS.

For example, we have some code that was developed and tested only for 2D: Operations on a graph of vertices and edges, like finding all intersection points (without tolerances required in 3D), find all closed loops, holes etc. Or Delaunay triangulation which is guaranteed only in 2D. Still the points, polygons and operations are of our 3D class libraries.

BTW, sometimes even if you have a 2D problem you may still want to use 3D operations like using cross product to find if an edge is "to the right" or "to the left" of another, etc.

We just use Z=Z_NO_VALUE. You can simply use Z=0 or `const float Z_NO_VALUE = -9999`;. Using the constant allows to have a separate code, or an assert, where only the 2D operation was developed or tested. You may want to add constructors with default values to Z if only the X,Y arguments are passed.